# SSL with proxy (https)

Tags: ssl, proxy

I was wondering if When using PROXY, does SSL (through HTTPS) secure the connection from the admins of the proxy, so they will not be able to see the content?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, when doing SSL connections with a proxy, you connect to the proxy and use something like the `CONNECT` HTTP verb, which just asks the proxy to connect to the remote host on the specified port. At that point, you're *not* secure; you can assume that the proxy is listening to the conversation. You then start an encrypted session with the remote host, using that host's public key, or rather the remote host uses its private key which you can check against its public key without needing to trust the proxy. The handshake algorithm is such that the proxy can't see what's inside the encrypted channel (since they don't know the session keys that each side picked as part of the SSL protocol). All the proxy can do is inject random detectable noise or cause the connection to get dropped; they can do denial-of-service attacks but can't affect the integrity or secrecy of any information actually transferred.

That's the beauty of using a proper crypto protocol like SSL.

Comment: Great, thats what I thought :) They can basically break the connection, but they won't be able to see the real content of the msgs between me and the server.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's possible that the proxy could spoof the remote host's certificate and public key, which would of course cause the browser to display dire warnings. If you (the end user) ignored these warnings, then the proxy would create two separate SSL connections, one between you and itself, and one between itself and the remote host. Between the two connections, the proxy would then have full access to the clear text.